# How to export React project as library that others can include in script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shared-libraries

I have used external libraries in the past for my projects that had a UI component (e.g. Intercom support chat) and that you would be able to include via a script tag in the HTML page like so

```
<script type="module" src="https://some.webpage.com/ui-script.js" async></script>
```

which then loads it into the window global variable and you can then initialize it like so

```
window.someApp.boot({
   APP_ID: 'APP_ID',
   user: {
      firstName:'Bob',
      lastName:'Bobby',
   }
});
```

How do I create such a library that others can include in a script tag and that attaches itself to the window as a ReactJS project? And are there any restrictions when it comes to modules that the ReactJS can use to render UI components (such as ant-d, tailwind, etc.). And what is usually the authentication model for this library to authenticate with its corresponding API? Is just using an API Key secure enough?